# Where does $\ell_{g} = \frac{\hbar^{2}}{2GMm^{2}}$ come from?

Tags: gravity, black-holes, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

$$\ell_{g} = \frac{\hbar^{2}}{2GMm^{2}}$$

This is an equation for the characteristic length scale that contains the constants $\hbar$ and $G$.

My question is where does this equation come from and if it has a significance rather than being  just dimensionally correct?

Comment: Where did you see this equation. Can you provide a link to it so we can see it in context?

Comment: The $2GM$ suggests the Schwarzschild radius $r_s=2GM/c^2$. If so that would make the equation $$\ell_g = \frac{\hbar^2}{c^2m^2}\frac{1}{r_s}$$

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
l_g = \frac{\hbar^{2}}{2GMm^{2}} = \frac{\left( \frac{\hbar}{mc} \right)^2}{\frac{2GM}{c^2}} = \frac{{ƛ}^2}{r_s}
$$
ie the square of the reduced Compton wavelength of a particle of mass $m$ divided by the Schwarzschild radius of a body of mass $M$.

At a guess, it's something to do with field theory on curved backgrounds, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: A follow up to the above statements, you can consider the Compton wavelength as the "characteristic length" of quantum effects while $r_s$ is the "characteristic length" of gravitational strength (interpreted as BH horizon size perhaps). So the ratio of the two gives an idea of the magnitude of the effect of both worlds, if $l_g$ becomes 1 it means both effects are relevant quantum and gravitational (roughly).

Comment: This is quite a weird combination as it already contains the dimensionless ratio $\frac{ƛ}{r_s}$ and it has more than one mass variable.

Answer (score 2):

It's one half of the analogue of [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius) for a (quantum) particle of mass $m$ orbiting a black hole of mass $M$.

The usual Bohr radius is defined as: $$ a_0 = \frac{4 \pi \varepsilon_0 \hbar^2}{m_{\text{e}} e^2}$$

We can recognize $e^2/(4\pi \varepsilon_0)$ as a coefficient in Coulomb law for the force between electron and proton:
$$
|F_{12}|=\frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0} \frac{e^2}{r^2}.$$

Now, the gravitational force for the particle orbiting a black hole (assuming Newtonian limit is applicable):
$$
|F_{12}|=\frac{G M m}{r^2}.
$$

Schrödinger equation for the nonrelativistic particle in the Newtonian field of a point mass is equivalent to equation for the hydrogen atom under substitution of $G M m $ with $e^2/(4\pi \varepsilon_0)$, so its solutions are characterized by the “gravitational Bohr radius”:
$$ a_g = \frac{\hbar^2}{GMm^2}.$$ 
OP's $\ell_g$ is one half of this value.

Applicability of Newtonian approximation could be checked by comparing $a_g$ (or $\ell_g$) with the Schwarzschild radius $r_s=2GM/c^2$. If $a_g\gg r_s$ then it is possible to have a *black hole atom*, quantum particle orbiting the black hole with the size of order $a_g$ described reasonably well by nonrelativistic theory.

Comment: But what is $l_g$ and why is it $\frac12 a_g$?

Comment: @sammygerbil: Within the ground state of hydrogen atom we could find a few meanings for half of Bohr radius: difference between most probable and average value of radius, decay constant of probability distribution with radius etc.

Comment: Neat conceit! Plugging $M=m_p$ and $m=m_e$ one gets an $\ell_g$ of the order of $10^{-32}$fm . This should safely chase away the graviphoton gaggle... It is evident that scaling up to planetary/stellar masses is far-fetched even for quantum gravity rants. Makes the Planck length appear astronomically huge by comparison.